# Multiple ResultSets were returned by the query Exception

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, anorm

**Note**

When I use the following dependencies (i.e., use an older version of Anorm) the below works as expected (no exception is thrown).

```
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")
 "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1202-jdbc42"
```

**Issue**

In PostgreSQL I have a user defined function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pPersonGet(p_personId bigint)
RETURNS TABLE (
    id bigint,
    shortname character varying,
    longname  character varying,
    avatarURL character varying,
    isActive boolean) AS
$$
BEGIN

return QUERY
select p.id, p.shortname, p.longname, p.avatarURL, p.isActive
 From person p
 where p_personId is null or p.id = p_personId;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When executing the following `find` function with Anorm 2.4

```
  val selectStmt =
    """
      select id, shortname, longname, avatarURL, isActive from pPersonGet({id});
    """
  ....
  ....
  val simple = {
    get[PersonID]("id") ~
      str("shortname") ~
      str("longname") ~
      str("avatarurl") ~
      get[Boolean]("isActive") map {
      case id~shortname~longname~avatarurl~isActive
      => Person(Some(id),
        Name(short, long),
        avatarurl,
        isActive)
    }
  }
  ....
  ....
  def find(id:Option[PersonID]) : List[Person] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
      anorm.SQL(selectStmt).on("id" -> id).as(simple *)
    }
  }
```

I get the following exception

```
[PSQLException: Multiple ResultSets were returned by the query.]
```

Dependencies:

```
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")
 "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1202-jdbc42"
 "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0"
```

Scala Version

```
scala-sdk-2.11.2
```

Comment: Would be useful to execute by hand the query to check the result.

Comment: That doesn't make a ton of sense. The only way multiple resultsets are possible in PostgreSQL is via `returns setof refcursor`, and that's turned into multiple resultsets by driver emulation. Please show the full stack trace and double check that the code you think is triggering this is what is actually triggering this. (Edit the question to add PostgreSQL and PgJDBC versions and the full stack trace, then comment here when done)

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug in your jdbc driver, have a look [here](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/386)

When query string includes ";\n" in the end of sql, query going to fail with your error. This bug was found in versions 1202 and 1203. I'd recommend you to use version 9.4-1204+ or 9.3-1101.